# cannot execute native update in JPA with JTA

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, jta

This is my application deployed on jboss 7.1.1 final, I've below EJB to access to database. But I cannot understand why error happened.

```
@Stateless
public class JPAServiceBean implements JPAServiceLocal, JPAServiceRemote {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "vms4_jboss7")
    EntityManager em;

    public Object getByNative(String query, Map<String, Object> params) {
        Query nativeQuery = em.createNativeQuery(query);
        setParameters(nativeQuery, params);
        return nativeQuery.getResultList();
    }

    public <T extends Serializable> T get(String namedQuery,
            Map<String, Object> params) {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery(namedQuery);
        setParameters(query, params);
        return (T)query.getSingleResult();
    }

    public <T extends Serializable> List<T> getList(String namedQuery,
            Map<String, Object> params) {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery(namedQuery);
        setParameters(query, params);
        return query.getResultList();
    }

    public void persist(Object o) {
        em.persist(o);
    }

    public void remove(Object o) {
        em.remove(o);
    }

    public EntityManager getEm() {
        return em;
    }

    private void setParameters(Query query, Map<String, Object> params) {
        if (query == null || params == null) {
            return;
        }
        for (String key : params.keySet()) {
            query.setParameter(key, params.get(key));
        }
    }

    public int executeUpdate(String query, Map<String, Object> params) {
        Query q = em.createQuery(query);
        setParameters(q, params);
        return q.executeUpdate();
    }

    public int executeNativeUpdate(String query, Map<String, Object> params) {
        try {
            //ut.begin();
            Query q = em.createNativeQuery(query);
            setParameters(q, params);
            return q.executeUpdate();
        } finally {
        }
    }

    public Object merge(Object o) {
        return em.merge(o);
    }

    public void refresh(Object o) {
        em.refresh(o);
    }

    public void detach(Object o) {
        em.detach(o);
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)
    public Object find(Class clazz, Object id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return em.find(clazz, id);
    }
}
```

Sometime I need to update data by native sql, so that, myapp run into the code of: 
`public int executeNativeUpdate(String query, Map<String, Object> params)`

And I got this error:

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Executing an update/delete query
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:139)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:204)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:306)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:190)
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.processInvocation(EJBRemoteTransactionPropagatingInterceptor.java:80)
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:59)
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:32)
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.TCCLInterceptor.processInvocation(TCCLInterceptor.java:45)
  at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:288)
  at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
  at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:165)
  at org.jboss.as.ejb3.remote.LocalEjbReceiver.processInvocation(LocalEjbReceiver.java:179)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:179)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.TransactionInterceptor.handleInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:43)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:181)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.ReceiverInterceptor.handleInvocation(ReceiverInterceptor.java:128)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBClientInvocationContext.sendRequest(EJBClientInvocationContext.java:181)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:136)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.doInvoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:121)
  at org.jboss.ejb.client.EJBInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBInvocationHandler.java:104)
  at $Proxy80.executeNativeUpdate(Unknown Source)
```

How can I do a native update sql in JPA/JTA.

Comment: How many native queries do you execute in a single transaction? It might be a timeout issue, if there are many native queries being executed in a single transaction.

Comment: Attach more stack trace. About transaction required `Caused by: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
  at org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractQueryImpl.executeUpdate(AbstractQueryImpl.java:96)`

Comment: That exception is because you're using `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.NOT_SUPPORTED)`. If you remove it, the default is `@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)` in EJBs (it is as good as removing it in its entirely). You should not need to explicitly mention it unless specific cases where you need to override the default one.

Comment: After removing, The same error happened. I think Hibernate/JPA implementation does not allow update by native sql, right? If my idea is wrong, could you show a snipper of code to help me.